# Select statement using list of key value pairs in where clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to figure out a way to do this using Entity framework, but I'll settle for the sql to do it.  Given a list of key value pairs, is there a way to select all rows from a table where table.colA = item.key and table.colB = item.value?

For instance given the following table data:

```
colA   colB   colC
------------------
1      3      abc
1      3      def
5      6      abc
5      8      def
9      10     abc
9      3      def
```

And the following List:

```
[{1, 3}, {5, 6}, {9, 3}]
```

I get the following rows returned:

```
colA   colB   colC
------------------
1      3      abc
1      3      def
5      6      abc
9      3      def
```

So the resulting query I need is something to the affect of:

```
select * from tableData
where
(colA = 1 AND colB = 3) OR
(colA = 5 AND colB = 6) OR
(colA = 9 AND colB = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join:

```cs
var input = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 3),
    new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5, 6),
    new KeyValuePair<int, int>(9, 3)
};

var results = from s in db.Source
              join i in input on new { s.colA, s.colB } equals new { colA = i.Key, colB = i.Value }
              select new { s.colA, s.colB, s.colC };
```

Or you could do it with a `Contains()`: (switching to a `Tuple` instead of `KeyValuePair`, just for fun!)

```
var input = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 3),
    new Tuple<int, int>(5, 6),
    new Tuple<int, int>(9, 3)
};

var results = from s in source
              where input.Contains(new Tuple<int, int>(s.colA, s.colB))
              select s;
```

If you are struggling with this due to entity framework, then this might do the job instead. It converts the key-value pair into a single string, separated by an arbitrary character (in this case a `:`):

```
var input = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 3),
    new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5, 6),
    new KeyValuePair<int, int>(9, 3)
};

//Combine the two values to be searched into a single one
var parsedInput = input.Select(i => i.Key + ":" + i.Value);

var results = from s in source
              where parsedInput.Contains(s.colA + ":" + s.colB)
              select s;
```

Comment: For the first one I get: {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Single, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}

Comment: I get a similar result for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to use Table-Valued parameters.
Then you could just do an inner join on the table parameter and the target table to retrieve the rows from the table.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-7) MSDN article for specifics on using Table-Valued parameters.

If you are working with SQL versions prior to 2008, or don't want to use table-valued parameters, then you can concatenate the two values together and use an IN clause, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CAST(ColA  as varchar(10)) + '|' + CAST(ColB as varchar(10)) IN ('1|3', '5|6', '9|3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Sqlfiddle demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff9728/5

```
;WITH split_names 
     AS (SELECT CONVERT(XML, '<cols><col>' 
                             + Replace( Replace(split.a.value('.','VARCHAR(100)'), 
                              '}', 
                            ''), 
                                    ',', '</col><col>') 
                             + '</col></cols>') AS xmlname 
         FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' 
                              + Replace(Replace(Replace( Replace( 
                              '[{1, 3}, {5, 6}, {9, 3}]', ']' 
                                  , ''), 
                                          '[', '' 
                          ), '{', ''), '},', '</M><M>') 
                          + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A 
                CROSS apply data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) 
SELECT colA,colB,colC 
FROM   <tablename> t 
       JOIN (SELECT xmlname.value('/cols[1]/col[1]', 'int') AS col1, 
                    xmlname.value('/cols[1]/col[2]', 'int') AS col2 
             FROM   split_names) a 
         ON t.cola = a.col1 
            AND t.colb = a.col2
```